# element switch class but don't get styles of the new class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a real-life timetable where you can watch where the students current be. They have six meetings a day. if a student exit the scool i want to delete him from the list. if i doubleclick the name i want to change the class from name to selected and change the backgoundcolor so if i would press the "Schüler löschen"-button all selected get deleted.

Here is the code:

```
            function createTable(){             
                var table = document.getElementById('table');

                for(var j = 0;j<names.length;j++) {
                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    row.classList.add('row');

                    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
                        if(i==0){
                            var cell = document.createElement("input");
                            cell.classList.add('name');
                            cell.value= names[j];
                            cell.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
                                alert(cell.classList);
                                cell.classList.add('selected');
                                alert(cell.classList);
                            });
                        }else if(i==4){
                            var cell = document.createElement("td");
                            cell.classList.add('spacer');

                        }else{
                            var cell = document.createElement("td");
                            cell.classList.add('cell');
                            cell.textContent = '';
                        }
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                    table.children[0].appendChild(row);
                }
            }
            createTable();
```

the css:

```
    input.name {
        width: 20em;
        background-color: #00ff00;
    }
    input.selected{
        background-color: #ff7f7f;
    }
```

The problem is if i double click the field the color dosent switch to red it stays green but the alert()-function shows that the class has switched

i've also tried

```
    cell.name {
        width: 20em;
        background-color: #00ff00;
    }
    cell.selected{
        background-color: #ff7f7f;
    }
```

Comment: `.input.selected{` you need to have `input` class remove the dot

Comment: `.input.selected{` you need to have `input` class remove the dot

Comment: sorry i've accidentally added it when i post the question. this dot is not in the real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `cell` class, and use this in that scope.

Try this:

```js
function createTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var names = ["TEST 1", " TEST 2"];

    for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.classList.add('row');

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                var cell = document.createElement("input");
                cell.classList.add('name');
                cell.value = names[j];
                cell.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
                    alert(cell.classList);
                    this.classList.remove('cell');
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                    alert(cell.classList);
                });
            } else if (i == 4) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.classList.add('spacer');

            } else {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
                cell.classList.add('cell');
                cell.textContent = '';
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.children[0].appendChild(row);
    }
}
createTable();
```

```css
input.name {
    width: 20em;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
input.selected{
    background-color: #ff7f7f;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

I didn't get why `cell` is `input element` and why do you need to added in `tr`